# Task scheduler in laravel homestead

Tags: laravel, homestead

I'm trying to get scheduled tasks to work in homestead.

First I created a command in called "randomUserCreatesubmission".

```
protected $signature = 'command:randomusercreatesubmission';
```

This command works just fine.

I then added it to a schedule in Kernel.php

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('disposable:update')->weekly();
    $schedule->command('command:randomusercreatesubmission')->everyMinute();
}
```

Then, after SSHing into homestead, I run the command

```
php artisan schedule:run
```

This returns the following:

```
Running scheduled command: '/usr/bin/php7.4' 'artisan' command:randomusercreatesubmission > '/dev/null' 2>&1
```

and it will run the "randomUserCreatesubmission" command once, immediately. However, I want it to run every minute, and it does not do that.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Did you setup a schedule worker / cron?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup a cron job. You can run in your terminal

```
crontab -e
```

then add to the end of your crontab

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and this command will run every minute.

Comment: This works. However, it's important to note that this should point to artisan, not just your project. So /path-to-your-project/project-name/artisan

Comment: It depends on how you write the command either `cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` or `php /path-to-your-project/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` will work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to start scheduler by adding below statement into `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Familiarize yourself with the official [Laravel Scheduler documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/scheduling).